# Trying to draw a Pie chart with AWT in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, awt, pie-chart

I'm trying to draw a Pie chart in Java (with AWT), where the "pieces" of the pie are set through the args parameters (user input).

Here's my code:

```
public class Pie extends Panel
{
    int value[];
    int start = 0;

    public Pie(String[] args)
    {
        int value[] = new int[args.length];

        for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) //Error at this line
        {
            value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i<value.length; i++)
        {
            g.fillArc(150, 150, 200, 200, start, value[i]);
            start = start + value[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame f = new Frame("Piechart");
        Pie p = new Pie(args);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }}
```

When I try to run the program with 4 args-parameters (i.e. java Pie 90 90 90 90), I get the error-message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pie.paint(Pie.java:24)
```

What can I change so that the program runs without errors?

Comment: Please check if g is null in paint().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- you are redeclaring `value[]` when allocate the array.
- you are using `Frame` when you should be using `JFrame`
- you should override `paintComponent` and not `paint`
- you should be using `JPanel` and not `Panel`

On the other hand, you extended the Panel and not the Frame.   This was exactly what you should have done and a mistake that many folks make.  All in all not a bad attempt at painting.

After you check this out, add the following right before the `for loop` in the `paintComponent` method

```
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Don't forget to change the `g`s to `g2d`

This tends to visually smooth out rough edges by doing some pixel averaging. Depending on what you are drawing, the effect can be dramatic at times.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pie extends JPanel
{
    int value[];
    int start = 0;

    Color[] colors = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.orange};
    public Pie(String[] args)
    {
        value = new int[args.length];

        for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++) //Error at this line
        {
            value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         if (value == null) {
             return;
         }
        for(int i = 0; i<value.length; i++) {
            g.setColor(colors[i%colors.length]);
            g.fillArc(150, 150, 200, 200, start, value[i]);
            start = start + value[i];
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Piechart");
        Pie p = new Pie(new String[]{"90","90","90", "90"});

        f.add(p);
        p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.repaint();
    }
}
```

I added colors so you could see the different slices of the pie chart.

For more on painting check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)